# Is it possible to find the available location for existing virtual machine using azure rest api?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rest-api

Hi everyone please help me . I want to get available location based on my existing virtual machine configuration using azure rest api.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the location where your VM exists from the [Virtual Machines - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get) API.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}?api-version=2020-12-01
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "name": "MyVM",
  "id": "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVM",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "location": "centralus",
  "tags": {
    ...
  },
  "properties": {
    ...
  },
...
}
```

**Web:** This page lists the availability of Azure Virtual Machines by region: [Products available by region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/global-infrastructure/services/?products=virtual-machines&regions=all)

**REST API:** The collection of locations where a certain resource type can be created can be fetched from the [Providers - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/list) API from [ProviderResourceType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/list#providerresourcetype) property in the response.

**PowerShell:** An easier alternative is to use the following command to get the supported locations for Azure VMs:

```
((Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq virtualMachines).Locations
```

Note that some services or VM features are only available in certain regions, such as specific VM sizes. To determine which SKUs are available in a region/zone, use the [Get-AzComputeResourceSku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azcomputeresourcesku?view=azps-5.5.0) cmdlet (or [Resource Skus - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list) REST API). Filter the results by location.

```
Get-AzComputeResourceSku | where {$_.ResourceType.Contains("virtualMachines")}
```

Another great option you may want to explore to move Azure resources between Azure regions is the [Azure Resource Mover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/) service. Resource Mover provides a simple and consistent experience with reduced move time and complexity. Checkout this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-virtual-machines) to move Azure VMs across regions.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need to move my virtual machine from current location to another location so firstly I have to check destination location have availability or not.

Comment: @Unknow Ohk, that wasn't clear from the question. Updated my response with the requested details. Please check.

Comment: @Unknow Do the provided inputs help?